# Is there an api i can call for getting iata codes for cities

Tags: api, geolocation

I'm developing a travel web app that has both departure and destination fields,is there an API I can call that takes the departure and destination and returns the iata codes for them ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Wikidata and the SPARQL query service of Wikidata to retrieve the IATA codes.

The requirement is that you know the title of the Wikipedia article of your departure/destination city. For bigger cities this should not be a problem because the Wikipedia title coincide with the city name. But for smaller places you probably need to use first the Wikipedia API to find the right article.

Once you know the Wikipedia title, you can run the following query on https://query.wikidata.org:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?iata WHERE {
<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles> schema:about ?city .
  ?airport wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q1248784;
           wdt:P131+ ?city;
           wdt:P238 ?iata
}
```

If you are new to Wikidata and SPARQL you find an introduction at https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/A_gentle_introduction_to_the_Wikidata_Query_Service.

In brief, the above lines do the following:

1. `<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles> schema:about ?city .` queries for the Wikidata item which is linked to the given Wikipedia article.
2. `?airport wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q1248784; wdt:P131+ ?city;` finds all airports which are located in this city.
3. `?airport wdt:P238 ?iata` returns the IATA code of that airport.

To programmatically access the data, call https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=...

Comment: I edited your query and selected also "?airport". I get back the WD:ID for each IATA code. Could you tell me what to adjust to retriev the the Airport name instead of the ED:ID?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ?iata ?airportLabel WHERE { <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles> schema:about ?city . ?airport wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q1248784; wdt:P131+ ?city; wdt:P238 ?iata SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". } }

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouagadougou does not respond any IATA, nor airport. But on Wikipedia there is mentioned an Aiport/IATA code, even via a Google search the Wiki fininds mentions it. How is that possible?